# How to add new profile for a particular user?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, associations

I have a user model and a profile model. In user.rb

```
has_one :profile
```

and in profile model

```
belongs_to :user
```

and when now I'm trying to create a profile for the current user in profiles#create

```
@profile = current_user.profile.new(params[:profile])
```

it throws an unknown method 'new' error.
How to fix this problem? Please help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`@profile = current_user.build_profile(params[:profile])`
`@profile.save!`